# Are there significant differences between the Chrome browser event loop versus the node event loop?

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom-events

Philip Roberts does a brilliant job explaining the browser event loop [here](http://vimeo.com/96425312) providing a clear explanation between the call stack, event loop, task queue, and then "outside" threads like webapis.  My question is do these parallel the equivalent components in the Node event loop and are they called basically the same thing.  That is, when I make a call using Node's file and web i/o libraries, these are things that happen outside the stack whose callbacks are queued in a task queue?

Comment: yeah, the core idea is the same. node.js uses Chrome's JS engine.

Comment: @apsillers Agreed. I'm just trying to determine if there were any major conceptual differences to be aware of.

Comment: A browser might have multiple event loops (for JS, for DOM, etc), but the concept is the same, yes.

Comment: @dandavis node.js does use Chrome's JS engine V8, but the event loop is not part of V8.  Node uses an event loop based off the C++ library libuv, while Chrome's is based off of libevent.  And Deno uses the Rust-based tokIO

Comment: @MaxCoplan: the question was are they "basically the same", and the answer was and is _yes_. My point was that universal V8 code doesn't care about the man behind the curtain.

Comment: @dandavis I agree.  But the reason they are "basically the same" is not because they both use V8.  It is just as "basically the same" with Firefox or Deno.  The reason they are "basically the same" is because their event loop implementations are similar

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> ...when I make a call using Node's file and web i/o libraries, these are things that happen outside the stack whose callbacks are queued in a task queue?

Yes, absolutely; they're asynchronous just like Ajax and `setTimeout` are asynchronous. They perform some operation outside of the call stack, and when they've finished that operation, they add an event to the queue to be processed by the event loop.

Node's API provides a kind of asynchronous no-op, [`setImmediate`](http://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers_setimmediate_callback_arg). For that function, the "some operation" I've mention above is "do nothing", after which an item is immediately added to the end of the event queue.

There is a more powerful [`process.nextTick`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_nexttick_callback) which adds an event to the *front* of the event queue, effectively cutting in line and making all other queued events wait. If called recursively, this can cause prolonged delay for other events (until reaching [`maxTickDepth`](http://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/process.html#process_process_maxtickdepth)).

Comment: FWIW: Node.js and Chrome do **not** use the same event loop implementation. Chrome/Chromium uses libevent, while node.js uses libuv.

Comment: @mscdex say whaaaaat -- good to know; I'll edit ASAP. If you have any references on hand, I'd love to put them in (I'll look it up myself, of course, and see if I can find one of my own).

Comment: [Here](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/chromium/+/master/third_party/libevent/README.chromium) is Chromium's source tree containing libevent. [Here](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/962e651476ce2035ce6e15eff5abd0f9c54e039c/src/node.cc#L3629-L3640) is node using libuv for the main event loop. Both do use v8 though and everything that comes with that (although node may use different versions of v8 than Chrome because Chrome updates pretty regularly).

Comment: Question: Is setTimeout(callback, 0); the same as setImmediate(callback)?

Comment: @DwarDoh they're similar, but behave in different ways. You can read more [here](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/event-loop-timers-and-nexttick/#setimmediate-vs-settimeout)

Answer (score 8):

Both are quite different. Browser's event loop doesn't depends on **I/O Operations**. But Node js event loop depends on **I/O operations**. Here the Node js event loop main goal is to separate out the main process and try to execute I/O operations and other timer API's asynchronously.

And another difference is we don't have a function **setImmediate()** in Browser. Difference between setTimeout() and setImmediate() is In setTimeout() call back function will execute after the given minimum threshold value in milliseconds. But in setImmediate() once any I/O Operation is done, if particular code is given inside setImmediate(), it will be executed first.

Because normally

```
setTimeout(() => {
    //some process
}, 0);
```

and

```
setImmediate(() => {
    //some process
});
```

are same and we can't predict which will execute first. But in Node js perspective under nodejs event loop mechanism if both are present under the callback of any I/O Operation, **setImmediate()** will get executed first. so,

```
let fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('/file/path', () => {
   setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('1');
   }, 0);
   setImmediate(() => {
      console.log('2');
   });
});
```

The output for above code will be,

```
2
1
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is another video [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u1kqx6AenYw) by Erin Zimmer, who presented in the JS Conference. She talks about event loop implementation with different tasks like micro and macro tasks as well as in other environments like Node JS, Browser and Web workers.

First watch Philip Roberts's video as mentioned by the OP and then this video.