# How are some Javascript features implemented differently between nodejs and the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, v8, libuv

According to the [v8 wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chrome_V8#Usage):

> V8 is intended to be used both in a browser and as a standalone
>   high-performance engine that can be integrated into independent
>   projects. V8 is used in the following software:
>
> - Google Chrome and all other Chromium-based web browsers, including Brave, Opera and Vivaldi ...
> - Node.js runtime environment

That in mind - nodejs is also using [libuv](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libuv) to [handle asynchronous events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js#V8):

> Node.js uses libuv to handle asynchronous events. Libuv is an
>   abstraction layer for network and file system functionality on both
>   Windows and POSIX-based systems such as Linux, macOS, OSS on NonStop,
>   and Unix.

Since both browsers and nodejs share common parts which are not part of the [web api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API) or nodes own [api](https://nodejs.org/api/index.html).

I assume that some features, which could be done with libuv - 
are implemented differently from the the browser.

What are some examples of API/JS implementations that are different between the two?

Comment: what do you mean by *different*?

Comment: Code that elevates the powers of libuv vs. the browser implementation which cannot do that.

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly but Timers API is implemented differently. Because `ref/unref` makes no sense in context of browser. Try `typeof setTimeout(() => {})`

Comment: Great example! Do you have more?

Comment: There is a talk of Bert Belder: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5soA6MCRODg explaining how the event loop in NodeJS made. Hope that gets you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting from [here](https://medium.com/the-node-js-collection/what-you-should-know-to-really-understand-the-node-js-event-loop-and-its-metrics-c4907b19da4c)

> Libuv is the library that provides the event loop to Node.js

So basically [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25751128/7021694) should give you an idea I suppose.